# match the dates of the month in the predefined labels in react charts

Tags: chart.js, react-chartjs-2

Is it possible to match the date of the data from the database (y-axis) to the predefined label in react line charts (x-axis)? I would like to see the changes per day if possible, and if there is no input on a specific day, it should only be stagnant/flat line until it changes again on the further days.

For now, I can map the data from the database into the chart in its proper dates, but it will only show those dates where there are inputs. Some data starts for 6th day of the month, so the chart starts at the 6th, it also skips the dates where there are no inputs.

````
    labels: userLexile.map((l) => new Date(l.date_added).getDate()), // day of month for x-axis
    datasets: [
      {
        label: `Lexile Growth | ${monthMap[new Date().getMonth()]}`,
        data: userLexile.map((l) => l.lexile), // value that the chart follows for y-axis
        backgroundColor: "#542ACA",
        borderColor: "#542ACA",
        borderWidth: 1,
        tension: 0.4,
        fill: "origin",
      },
    ],
  };```
````

Comment: Probably the best thing is to use time scale instead of a category one.